# Optimum settings for apache/php webserver with separate mysql database server

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2, virtualbox

I'm having a mysql connection speed issue with my home development setup.  I have two VM's (VirtualBox running on a Ubuntu host).  One is my WEBSERV with apache2/php and one is by DBSERV with mysql and postgres (both are ubuntu server 10.4 LTS).  Also, i have mysql installed on the WEBSERV as well and this was only done before i decided to have a separate database VM. When querying a simple table from the WEBSERV mysql via a php webpage is runs very fast ( < 1sec) -- just like it should.  However, when i run the same simple query but against the separate DBSERV mysql via a php webpage it works but it takes + 5 seconds to return a request.  It's not like it doesn't work -- it just takes way too long.

At first i thought it was a network issue but the pinging the DBSERV from the WEBSERV take 1-2ms.  And to further test, when i run the same simple query from WEBSERV via a php webpage querying postgres on DBSERV it is very fast -- just like it should be.

So, it looks like it is some sort of setting either with apache/php on WEBSERV or with mysql on DBSERV.  I'm at a loss as to what settings/setup i need to modify.  It would be one thing if the slow request just didn't work at all -- but it does... it's just extremely slow and i can't figure out why that is the case.

Anyone point me in a direction on settings to check?!?

Thanks...M

Comment: Found the issue -- add the 'skip-name-resolve' to the my.cnf file on DBSERV and that fixed the delay.  Found it on serverfault ( http://serverfault.com/questions/144492/mysql-connection-is-slow-5seconds )

Comment: Why dinn't you answer your own question so you can close it?

Answer (score 0):

If  you're getting 5 second delays, you may want to add skip-name-resolve to the my.cnf file.  That will prevent it from doing a lookup on your IP, and possibly timing out.