# PHP slow to talk to MySQL on same host

Tags: mysql, php, ubuntu-10.04

I have a VPS (OpenVZ) running Ubuntu 10.04:

- nginx 1.0.5
- php 5.3.5
- mysql 5.1.41

I have installed WordPress on it and noticed in Firebug that the initial connection to index.php takes several seconds (from 4 up to 13 seconds at one time).

What makes me think it's an issue with MySQL:

- if I install a caching plugin that bypasses the database, the lag dissapears
- the queries themselves execute in a couple of miliseconds

I've tried addding skip-name-resolve or skip-networking to my.cnf as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/144492/mysql-connection-is-slow-5seconds), with no luck.

One other thing I noticed is that the php-fpm process spikes to 100% CPU load while the page is generated.

I have tried using apache instead and even nginx in front of apache, but now the apache process hogged all the CPU.

One last thing: I run this exact same application on another VPS with similar configuration and there's no delay; index.php loads in under half a second.

Any suggestions on how I might find out what the problem is?

Comment: Does connecting to the database via the command line exhibit the same delay?

Comment: @Shane Madden: Nope; if I log into ssh and then run the `mysql` command, it's fast.

Comment: What process exactly is a top CPU consumer when CPU usage is at 100%? Is it mysql?

Comment: @Shane Madden: Hm... it's actually php-fpm that's spiking. But when I enable the caching, it doesn't anymore.

Comment: What happens when you run all the queries from the page from the commandline?

Comment: @Dana the Sane: Like I said, the actual query time is small: 0.77 seconds in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try to use IP, instead of hostname when connecting to your MySQL (use dig to diagnose DNS problems),
- use [High Performance MySQL Tuning Script](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl/blob/master/mysqltuner.pl), which will give you the idea about some problems in MySQL server,
- use strace or tcpdump to debug your issues ([here are some examples](http://drupal.org/node/1817744)),
- upgrade your php & mysql and check if the problem persist,

Answer (score 2):

If php-fpm uses 100% of CPU this is hardly MySQL-related problem, so you should start to examine your PHP code to find which piece of code causes the delay. I recommend to use XDebug for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is MySQL related, since it only happens when MySQL is involved; maybe it has something to do with the PHP MySQL driver.

Comment: It's good to get a sample of profiling data anyway. It will show you the exact place where your app spends so much time. Another approach is to try to call `strace -p` on php-fpm process but strace data won't be relevant enough since strace knows nothing about your app internals.

Comment: I tried switching to apache and the problem persists, only now it's the apache process hogging the CPU. The funny thing is that I run the same app on a similar VPS with no delay. So yeah, I guess profiling is the last hope.

Comment: Ok, did a profiling, looked at it through KCacheGrind; didn't learn anything. :|

Comment: Okay, maybe it's time to strace, but just to be sure, could you please upload your cachegrind.out somewhere and post a link here?

Comment: Sure: http://lomo.scribu.net/cachegrind.out.3974 (it's 12mb).

Comment: Thanks, got it and examined it a bit. `make_entry` method of `MO` class is a clear winner (it's in a `mo.php` file). And it was called 3161 times for a single web request! Something is definitely not right with it.

Comment: Yeah, but that's used in every WordPress installation (including on the other VPS, which works fine). Thanks for looking though.

Comment: By the way, do you use any kind of PHP opcode cache? I see that `require_once` takes a lot of time, please try to install APC or eAccelerator or XCache, all of them are free.

Comment: No, I'm not using any opcode caching; need to figure this out first. I did a strace and php-fpm seems to be making tens of thousands of gettimeofday() calls for a single request.

Comment: chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1262/discussion-between-scribu-and-alex

Answer (score 1):

I would check the firewall, the php-fpm to mysql connection (consider switching to pipe/socket).

With all this I suppose the php-fpm was properly installed/upgraded, maybe disable some of the modules.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Default firewall rules; MySQL has `skip-networking` so I presume a socket is used.